# Doubt regarding trends in modern periodic table

Tags: periodic-trends, periodic-table

We know that atomic radius decreases along a period and increases along a group. (Same goes for metallic character)

But if we take 2 elements A & B(A is at somewhere in the top and left in periodic table and B is somewhere is below and right of B) then which among A and B will have greater atomic radius and more metallic character?

Comment: If you increase both (positive) A and B, will A/B increase or decrease? If you get answer for this, you will have answer for your question.

Comment: The question is looking very vague, to me at least.

Comment: Title is not matching the question (if I understand the question).

Comment: Such generalisations are hardly useful. Despite having a somewhat similar atomic diameter and "metallicity", A and B will have very different chemical properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the period effect for B overrules the group effect, B will have the greater atomic radius than A.

If the group effect for B overrules the period effect, B will have the smaller atomic radius than A.

The same for the element metallic character.

For the p elements, you can see the metalicity boundary goes somewhat diagonally.